# Mat OpenCV Rect ROI: access violation

Tags: opencv, rect, mat, roi

I am new to OpenCV image processing. My task is simple. I have to get 1/4th of an image (lower 1/4). The size of the image is 320 x 240. I used ROI `Rect` in a `Mat` object to get it.

```
Mat img_roi;
img_roi= image(cv::Rect(0,180,320,240));
```

I get the following error:

> First-chance exception at 0x7669c41f in first.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception >at memory location 0x0041ec30..
>   Unhandled exception at 0x7669c41f in first.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at >memory location 0x0041ec30..

If I specify `Rect(0,0,320,60)` in the above code, I am getting the result (which is upper half) and the code works for some other values, for eg `Rect (0,0,320,240)`, i.e., a full image. But not with lower quarter values (0,180,320,240).

I should also tell that I am getting the result by using `Iplimage`. Only `Mat` object creates the problem.

I would be really thankful if any of you can guide me in solving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lower 1/4 of your image is `Rect(0,180,320,60)`. It is not `Rect(0,180, 320, 240)` nor it is  `Rect(0,0,320,60)`.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael Burdinov. It worked. Importantly, I understood my mistake. I wonder, how it worked with Iplimage ?

Comment: You are welcome. As for why it worked with IplImage, I think that the exception you got was thrown by OpenCV itself, i.e. Mat constructor failed at sanity check. I am not sure that the same sanity check is performed by IplImage. Access to un-allocated memory is always bad, but not always creates exception.

Answer (score 2):

The arguments of `cv::Rect` are:

`cvRect(int x, int y, int width, int height);`

Here the x and Y represents the top-left corner whereas width and height represents the number of columns and rows you want to have in your image.

In your case:  rows = 320, cols =240

so to get the **lower-left  corner** use:

`Rect( 0, image.rows/2, image.cols/2, image.rows/2  )`

and if you want to have **lower-right** image then use:

`Rect( image.cols/2, image.rows/2, image.cols/2, image.rows/2  )`